# Google Nearby ultrasonic messages between iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, google-nearby

I'm trying to use Google Nearby to send messages using exactly ultrasound (not BLE or WiFi). I have no idea why it doesn't work.
I haven't found any additional steps for get this work.

No errors. Log says that publishing is successful. But subscriber doesn't react at all

Should apps request microphone permissions?
Should app check anything else?
Is there any ready working sample of ultrasonic messages between iOS and Android?

iOS part:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    GNSMessageManager *_messageManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _messageManager = [[GNSMessageManager alloc]
            initWithAPIKey:@"MY_API_KEY"
               paramsBlock:^(GNSMessageManagerParams *params) {
                   params.microphonePermissionErrorHandler = ^(BOOL hasError) {
                       NSLog(@"Microphone Permission Error:%@", hasError ? @"YES" : @"NO");

                   };
                   params.bluetoothPowerErrorHandler = ^(BOOL hasError) {
                       NSLog(@"Bluetooth Power Error:%@", hasError ? @"YES" : @"NO");

                   };
                   params.bluetoothPermissionErrorHandler = ^(BOOL hasError) {
                       NSLog(@"Bluetooth Permission Error:%@", hasError ? @"YES" : @"NO");
                   };
               }];
    [GNSMessageManager setDebugLoggingEnabled:YES];
    [GNSPermission setGranted:YES];
    GNSPermission *nearbyPermission = [[GNSPermission alloc] initWithChangedHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
        NSLog(@"Nearby Permission:%@", granted ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    }];

    id <GNSSubscription> subscription = [_messageManager subscriptionWithMessageFoundHandler:^(GNSMessage *message) {
                NSLog(@"subscriptionWithMessageFoundHandler");

                UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Google Nearby Message" message:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:message.content encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
                [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
                                                                          messageLostHandler:^(GNSMessage *message) {
                                                                              // Remove the name from the list
                                                                          }
                                                                                 paramsBlock:^(GNSSubscriptionParams *subscriptionParams) {
                                                                                     subscriptionParams.strategy = [GNSStrategy strategyWithParamsBlock:^(GNSStrategyParams *params) {
                                                                                         params.discoveryMediums = kGNSDiscoveryMediumsAudio;
                                                                                         params.discoveryMode = kGNSDiscoveryModeScan;
                                                                                     }];
                                                                                 }
    ];


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)publishDidClick:(id)sender {
    NSString *string = self.publisherField.text;
    if (string == nil || string.length == 0) {
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Google Nearby" message:@"Please put some text into field before publishing" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {
        @try {
            GNSMessage *gnsMessage = [GNSMessage messageWithContent:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            id <GNSPublication> publication = [_messageManager publicationWithMessage:gnsMessage
                                                                          paramsBlock:^(GNSPublicationParams *params) {
                                                                              params.strategy = [GNSStrategy strategyWithParamsBlock:^(GNSStrategyParams *params) {
                                                                                  params.discoveryMediums = kGNSDiscoveryMediumsAudio;
                                                                              }];
                                                                          }];

        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception occurred: %@, %@", exception, [exception userInfo]);
        }
    }


}
```

iOS logs:

```
2017-02-17 22:33:33.701925 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Nearby Permission:YES
2017-02-17 22:33:35.842523 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-02-17 22:33:35.853836 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2017-02-17 22:33:40.630279 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Publish (mediums: 1, broadcast/scan: 3, beacons: 0/0/0, background: 0)
2017-02-17 22:33:40.677551 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Unpublish
2017-02-17 22:33:40.681520 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Tokens: 0 good, 0 bad, 0 broadcast
2017-02-17 22:33:40.681663 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC request: 0 token(s), 0 beacon(s), 0 directive(s)
2017-02-17 22:33:40.705243 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC request: Publish: 1
2017-02-17 22:33:40.705933 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC request: Unpublish: 1
2017-02-17 22:33:41.625510 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC response: Success
2017-02-17 22:33:41.626823 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC response: 6 directive(s), 0 token(s), 0 message(s), 1 publication results(s), 0 subscription results(s)
2017-02-17 22:33:41.641955 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Tokens: 0 good, 0 bad, 0 broadcast
2017-02-17 22:33:41.642170 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC request: 0 token(s), 0 beacon(s), 0 directive(s)
2017-02-17 22:33:41.889006 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC response: Success
2017-02-17 22:33:41.889370 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC response: 0 directive(s), 0 token(s), 0 message(s), 0 publication results(s), 0 subscription results(s)
2017-02-17 22:33:46.337377 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Publish (mediums: 1, broadcast/scan: 3, beacons: 0/0/0, background: 0)
2017-02-17 22:33:46.342647 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Unpublish
2017-02-17 22:33:46.350383 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Tokens: 0 good, 0 bad, 0 broadcast
2017-02-17 22:33:46.350746 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC request: 0 token(s), 0 beacon(s), 0 directive(s)
2017-02-17 22:33:46.351382 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC request: Publish: 1
2017-02-17 22:33:46.351675 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC request: Unpublish: 1
2017-02-17 22:33:46.937869 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC response: Success
2017-02-17 22:33:46.938223 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC response: 6 directive(s), 0 token(s), 0 message(s), 1 publication results(s), 0 subscription results(s)
2017-02-17 22:33:46.951400 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Tokens: 0 good, 0 bad, 0 broadcast
2017-02-17 22:33:46.951618 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC request: 0 token(s), 0 beacon(s), 0 directive(s)
2017-02-17 22:33:47.174414 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC response: Success
2017-02-17 22:33:47.174676 GoogleNearbySample[5727:1608902] Report RPC response: 0 directive(s), 0 token(s), 0 message(s), 0 publication results(s), 0 subscription results(s)
```

Android part:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 12341;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View view = findViewById(R.id.button);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PublishOptions publishOptions = new PublishOptions.Builder().setStrategy(new Strategy.Builder().setDiscoveryMode(Strategy.DISCOVERY_MODE_SCAN)
                        .setDistanceType(Strategy.DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT).build()).build();
                Nearby.Messages.publish(mGoogleApiClient, new Message("Hello Artur".getBytes()), publishOptions).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        Log.i("Nearby", status.getStatusMessage());
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                    .build();

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        SubscribeOptions subscribeOptions = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
                .setStrategy(new Strategy.Builder().setDiscoveryMode(Strategy.DISCOVERY_MODE_SCAN)
                        .setDistanceType(Strategy.DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT).build()).build();
        Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, new MessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFound(Message message) {
                super.onFound(message);
                Log.i("Nearby", "Subscribed found.");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), new String(message.getContent()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }, subscribeOptions).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.i("Nearby", "Subscribed successfully.");
                } else {
                    Log.i("Nearby", "Could not subscribe.");
                    // Check whether consent was given;
                    // if not, prompt the user for consent.
                    handleUnsuccessfulNearbyResult(status);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleUnsuccessfulNearbyResult(Status status) {
        Log.i("Nearby", "Processing error, status = " + status);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d("onConnectionSuspended", String.valueOf(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d("onConnectionFailed", connectionResult.getErrorMessage());

    }
}
```

Android logs:

```
02-17 22:32:56.158 11325-11325/? I/Nearby: Subscribed successfully.
02-17 22:32:59.929 11325-11325/? D/NearbyMessagesClient: Emitting client lifecycle event ACTIVITY_STOPPED
02-17 22:32:59.930 11325-11325/? D/NearbyMessagesClient: Emitting client lifecycle event CLIENT_DISCONNECTED
02-17 22:33:28.890 11325-11325/? I/Nearby: Subscribed successfully.
02-17 22:33:45.867 11325-11325/? I/Nearby: SUCCESS
02-17 22:33:46.542 11325-11325/? I/Nearby: SUCCESS
02-17 22:33:47.137 11325-11325/? I/Nearby: SUCCESS
02-17 22:33:47.779 11325-11325/? I/Nearby: SUCCESS
02-17 22:33:48.422 11325-11325/? I/Nearby: SUCCESS
02-17 22:33:49.053 11325-11325/? I/Nearby: SUCCESS
02-17 22:34:18.477 11325-11325/? D/NearbyMessagesClient: Emitting client lifecycle event ACTIVITY_STOPPED
02-17 22:34:18.479 11325-11325/? D/NearbyMessagesClient: Emitting client lifecycle event CLIENT_DISCONNECTED
02-17 22:36:47.996 11325-11325/? D/NearbyMessagesClient: Failed to emit client lifecycle event ACTIVITY_STOPPED due to GmsClient being disconnected
02-17 22:36:47.997 11325-11325/? D/NearbyMessagesClient: Failed to emit client lifecycle event CLIENT_DISCONNECTED due to GmsClient being disconnected
```

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work" you need to explain more detailed what exactly doesn't work, the error you get, the expected outcome and what happens instead. And also what line of code the problems occurs at.

Comment: @Emil You are right. No errors. Log says that publishing is successful. But subscriber doesn't react at all

Comment: Can you paste the console log messages you're seeing when you run the app and start publishing/subscribing?  You've got debug logging turned on already, so you should see logs that look something like this:  

Server URL: ...  
Device ID: ...  
...

Comment: @DanWebb I added logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artur, you need to store the publication object in a property or ivar.  The publication is active as long as the publication object exists. To stop publishing, release the publication object.  Ditto for the subscription.

I realize the pub/sub code examples in the [Cocoapod documentation](https://cocoapods.org/pods/NearbyMessages) is misleading.  I'll fix it in the next release.